# how to navigate one page to another jsp page according to dropdown selection using servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new in jsp and Servlet. I have form including only one drop-down menu in jsp.
1. student
2. faculty
if i select student then it have to navigate in student.jsp. if i select faculty then it have to navigate in faculty.jsp.Using |Submit| button.

I don't want to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, Choose value in your dropdown and submit the page,

```
<form action="your_servlet">
     <select name="category" >
        <option value="1">Student</option>
        <option value="2">Faculty</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

And in your servlet,

```
Integer selectedValue = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category"));
```

This will give you the value either `1` or `2`, based on that you can easily redirect.

Comment: You are welcome, Mark it as accepted answer. So other users will get benefit from this answer.